# Layout labels from left to right

Tags: java, swing, layout

I would like some help on choosing or creating a layout for a component to which I will add labels at runtime.  For example the component size will be 400*50 and empty when the application start up.  Then some action will add a first label at position 0, the second at position first label's width, the third at first label's width + second label's width and so on.  A bit like the `FlowLayout` except that I want my labels to start at the left of the container and not in the center.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `FlowLayout` and call `setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);` (or use one of the constructors that takes an alignment code).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout%28int%29)